How can I get process id of the game launched by any launcher
I stuck at getting the game process id. I need to be detect when the game is closed and than I have to take some action. But I couldn't got the right process id so I couldn't detected that the game is closed.
here's how I run the games on different laucnhers. I am using C# script to run games from launchers.
psi.FileName = "steam://rungameid/" + LaunchID ;
psi.FileName = "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/" + LaunchID + "?action=launch&silent=true";
psi.FileName = ":\\Riot Games\\\Riot Client\\RiotClientServices.exe" + LaunchID + "--launch - patchline = live";

the ways I have tried so far:
I have tried to get the processes running within 10 seconds based on the time I did the above operations. the problem is that anticheat services are running before the game and I can't get the right process. also some games run with multiple processes which makes it hard to track.
In another discussion I tried to solve it by finding the process whose parent process is the launcher, but there can be several parents in between or the parent can be null, so this doesn't work either.

"How can I get process id of the game launched by any launcher"? Not easily, I'd assume. I think you'd need some somewhat fuzzy diagnostics, for instance looking at which process owns the window the user has in the foreground the most after you've started a game (which is likely the game window).
